# Viewing a whole photo album with Windows "Photos"

Tags: windows, photos, viewer

I am opening a folder which contains a certain amount of images. When I double click one single element, the Windows Photos software actually does only show this single photo. Even if the folder contains dozens of other pictures, there there is no possibility to move forward/backward.

It is not comfortable to first select all photos and then navigate through them. Is there an alternative to this approach? If not, I would appreciate you to recommend me a better viewer.

Comment: Assuming you are using Windows 10 and Windows 10 Photos, it is easy to scroll through. Open the first picture and you should should see right (>) and left (<) arrows at the sides of the photo. This allows you to scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might need to move the mouse to the right/left side of the photo and then we can see right (>) and left (<) arrows.

Besides, you can also directly use the left & right arrow keys on your keyboard to switch between the previous and next photo.